# My ImageCircle is resizing itself in xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms

I am using ImageCircle plugin for xamarin forms
and it works well sometimes, when the picture is a kind of square...
But, when it's a rectangle, my image is resized and it's not that I planned
what Can I do to the image stop resize?

my code

```
        <controls:CircleImage WidthRequest="75" HeightRequest="75" Grid.Row ="0" Grid.Column="1" Source="cadastrarPhoto.png"  x:Name="cadastrar_foto_perfil">
```

I seted a fix height and width as you can see, but it didn't solve my problem, maybe because this circle image is a child of a grid and its grandfather (lol) is a relative layout but I really don't know if WidthRequest can change because of that...

How it always should be

[image]

How it is when the image is a rectangle:

[image]

EDIT---------------------------------------------
I put it in a Stach layout and I defined Aspect as fit...it helped but didnt solve...

```
 <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="75" HeightRequest="75" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
      <controls:CircleImage Aspect="AspectFit" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Source="cadastrarPhoto.png" x:Name="cadastrar_foto_perfil">
        <controls:CircleImage.GestureRecognizers>
          <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ChamaPickerImage"/>
        </controls:CircleImage.GestureRecognizers>
      </controls:CircleImage>
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Did you tried set `Aspect="AspectFit"` to your image control?

Comment: Yeah...I will post more about my code here...cause I updated it

Comment: Right, I Did...Could you see?

Comment: your controls:CircleImage's verticaloptions and horizontaloptions are wrong. they're set to expand, so the image will fill available space.

Comment: I am changing it now

Comment: It didnt solve too

Comment: which version of ImageCircle plugin are you using?

Comment: I am using v1.8.1

Comment: can you post your full layout xaml?

Comment: I am having a hard time recreating this issue - is only background in this control stretched or entire image? The reason I ask is it could be parent control's background that might be culprit here - for eg Frame with circular radius.

Comment: the problem is the image size...if the image is a square...its ok...but if its a rectangle...then the circleimage is not a perfect circle, as i showed in the images here, the image still in its format when it should be a perfect circle and not a rectangle with circular bounds (like is happening now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the api that I was using.
Now I use ffimage

Answer (score 0):

Setting your `HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"` is what is causing you issues.

Instead, try setting both `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` to a vaule that doesn't expand (Start, Center, End)

**Note:** I've noticed that you actually have to explicitly set `HorizontalOptions` to something that doesn't expand in order to get iOS to avoid stretching your CircleImage. Simply leaving it blank will default to stretching the image.

Answer (score 0):

In the image, instead of HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" or VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand", just set it as "Start", "Center" or "End".

By default if you set it as "xxExpand" or do not set it at all, Xamarin iOS expands the image...